# How to set Database connection string for Windows azure - worker role in .cscfg file..?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-worker-roles

Have to set the Database connection string in the .cscfg file, not the app.config (In my windows azure worker role application).
Can anyone help me on this..?

Thanks in Adavance.
Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

If you're thinking about setting the connection string in `<connectionStrings></connectionStrings>` element in `.cscfg` file, you can't do that. Configuration file only takes name/value pair. So you would do something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ServiceConfiguration serviceName="Web.Azure" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceConfiguration" osFamily="3" osVersion="*" schemaVersion="2013-03.2.0">
  <Role name="Worker">
    <Instances count="2" />
    <ConfigurationSettings>
      <Setting name="DatabaseConnectionString" value="your database connection string" />
    </ConfigurationSettings>
  </Role>
</ServiceConfiguration>
```

and then read the connection string in your code like:

```
var databaseConnectionString = RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("DatabaseConnectionString")
```

and use that connection string for your database calls.

Comment: Also - be sure to update your csdef to force all configurations to include the connection string